# Best practices for selectors in a website with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Don't know if this is an appropriate question, but I will try. I would like to know from you guys who are more experienced with testing, what would be the best practice to work with selecting, for example, links in a website. Would it be better to use jus "link=Link Name" or go for xpath as this "//a[contains(@class,"if desktop-menu-action")][normalize-space()="Mina skador"]". Or is it better to use "//*[contains(text(),'Betalningar')]" as we have a dynamic content all over the place. I have tried to search for such info, but really never found anything except just basic stuff about xpath.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to better optimize scripts in Selenium IDE for a better performance.

[Example script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W7Jd.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there is anyway to use Id's as much as possible - I see you have some ID's like 'DocumentsPage', 'ActivitiesPage' its not always possible to just use these standalone however. When I use XPath's I tend to be careful when depending on text as this text could change in future or not be applicable in other languages. I typically try ID first on it's own, by an attribute e.g title, classname etc and then if needed add another layer like some text or chained xpath - this is my last preferred selector but again may be needed depending on use case.

Disclaimer -  I'm not super experienced, have a few years under my belt but still learning hence why I'm here on StackOverflow trying to learn from other professionals